# Application not geting data from Ehcache for first request

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

I am trying to fetch data from cache which is stored in disk of my local path. But when the first request is sent from browser it is not entering into cache, instead it is overriding the existing cache (although same data exists in cache) by fetching data from database.

How can i get data from cache if it already present by not creating new for every first request

i am invoking cache like this

```
public class ServiceListener implements ServletContextListener {
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ServiceListener.class);
public static CacheManager cm;

public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {

}

public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    log.info("initialized");
    // CacheManager c = CacheManager.newInstance();
    cm = CacheManager.getInstance();
}
```

}

cache configuration

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="true"
monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true">
<diskStore path="/home/teja/projects/Main/cacheExp" />
<cache name="cache1" maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
    maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000" eternal="true" diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
    timeToIdleSeconds="3000" timeToLiveSeconds="60000"
    diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="150" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
    diskPersistent="true" transactionalMode="off">
    <!-- <persistence strategy="localRestartable" /> -->
</cache></ehcache>
```

sample usage

```
String key = width + " " + height;
            if (!cache.isKeyInCache(key)) {
                log.info("entered database");
                List<List> got = support.getDataFromDb(width, height);
                imageList = got.get(0);
                priceList = got.get(1);
                seatList = got.get(2);
                widthList = got.get(3);
                heightList = got.get(4);
                cache.put(new Element(key, got));
            } else {
                log.info("entered cache");
                List got = (List) cache.get(key).getObjectValue();
                imageList = (List<String>) got.get(0);
                priceList = (List<Float>) got.get(1);
                seatList = (List<String>) got.get(2);
                widthList = (List<Integer>) got.get(3);
                heightList = (List<Integer>) got.get(4);
            }
```

Thank you

Comment: whether data available you have to confirm cache key you are fetching.cache is not a intelligent thing. If  you invoke with same key set it should return otherwise it is not.

Comment: i am invoking with same key, for first request it is always overriding existing cache

Comment: can you share the code like this,     @Cacheable(value="listByPageIndexAndQuestionSet", key="#pageIndex.toString().concat('-').concat(#questionSet.toString())")
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    @Override
    public List<Question> listByPageIndex(int pageIndex,int questionSet)

Comment: "for first request it is always overriding existing cache" ? that mean are you pre-loading data for cache?

Comment: i am not using annotations i am using xml file

Comment: plz check the edited question

Comment: where is the DAO method code?

Comment: Normally in first request is the time it hit DB and put data into cache. Are you pre-loading everything to cache one time before use application?

Comment: first i hit database and stored data in cache. I restarted server and again sent the request with same data but then also it is overriding

Comment: did you check cache after restarting the server. cache may gone with restart.

Comment: yes i checked, cache is available with data after restart.

Comment: The shared code sample only indicates how you initialise the cache manager. Nothing indicates the cache (manager) configuration nor how you interact with the cache in your application. Without this information, nothing but guesses can be made. please update the question with these informations.

Comment: i updated my question plz check